# Application Insights does not flush if main thread is deadlocked?

Tags: c#, deadlock, azure-application-insights

I'm investigating a issue on my application, and I'm running out of ideas. The symptoms are:

- complete server unresponsiveness from user perspective
- no abnormal CPU or memory consumption
- slow-moving database connection "hoarding"
- slow-moving THREADING "hoarding"
- application insights blackout

What it looks like:
The server is alive and accepting requests. Because of dependency injection, each request that arrives opens up a database connection, which also explains the thread hoarding. But for some reason like "[bad async practices](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)" (not the case here, already checked for that) all threads are got in a deadlock state.

So I was wondering, if the main thread is deadlocked, is application insights still able to flush its logs?

Comment: If you can come up with a small repro this might be a great question on Application Insights SDK GitHub repository.

Comment: As @ZakiMa suggested, you can open an issue on GitHub: [ApplicationInsights-dotnet](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues)